# MySQL get records by hour interval

Tags: mysql, timeline

I need to show a timeline from MySQL table. Basically retrieve count of records by each hour. My TimeSigned column is DateStamp

Login

```
Id  TimeSigned            MarkedBy
1.  2016-03-14 05:12:17    James
2.  2016-03-14 05:30:10    Mark
3.  2016-03-14 06:10:00    James
4.  2016-03-14 07:30:10    Mary
```

I am using following query but it brings wrong results.

```
SELECT COUNT(Id) From Logins WHERE HOUR(TimeSigned) > 5 AND HOUR(TimeSigned) < 6
```

I was expecting it to return a count of 2 (i.e. 1 and the 2 record are within the 5-6 time range) but it brings back 0.

I have created a sqlfiddle here [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/601cb8/1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `=` in your first condition. there is nothing between 5 and 6 so it will give count 0

```
SELECT COUNT(Id) From Logins WHERE HOUR(TimeSigned) >= 5 AND HOUR(TimeSigned) < 6
```

Answer (score 1):

HOUR() returns the hour part so it's whole numbers.
There are no whole numbers that are greater than 5 and less than 6.
I think you want to just look for the hour is equal to 5

```
SELECT COUNT(Id) From Logins WHERE HOUR(TimeSigned) = 5
```

Or if you want you could return counts for each hour by doing

```
SELECT COUNT(Id) as Count,HOUR(TimeSigned) as Hour  From Logins GROUP BY HOUR(TimeSigned)
```